# exercise on Huffman encode

Tags: huffman-coding

I have these 4 symbols with their probabilities:

```
 x   P(x)
 --------
 1   0.3
 2   0.3
 3   0.2
 4   0.2
```

I built the Huffman tree in this way:

[image]

and I obtainded:

```
 x   P(x)   C(x)
 ----------------
 1   0.3     0
 2   0.3     10
 3   0.2     110
 4   0.2     111
```

it's correct? Because according to the solution the results should be:

```
 x   P(x)   C(x)
 ----------------
 1   0.3     00
 2   0.3     01
 3   0.2     10
 4   0.2     11
```

Why?
Yet I followed the steps shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Please don't delete your question after you get an answer.  That's disrespectful to the person who spent time writing an answer.  We want to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will help not only you but others as well; deleting the question prevents anyone else from benefiting, and prevents the person who answered from receiving reputation for their answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to check whether your answer has a chance of being correct is to compute the average code length. Your encoding gives the average length of $2.1$, which is greater than using a code of fixed length $2$, so it can't be correct.

If you follow the priority queue algorithm from the source you cite, then you would notice that after merging nodes 3 and 4 you get one supernode of priority 0.4. Now your queue would have three elements of priorities $0.3, 0.3,$ and $0.4$. Thus, you would next merge elements corresponding to priorities $0.3$ and $0.3$ (the algorithm works by merging two nodes with lowest priorities), which happen to be nodes 1 and 2.